# PHP $_GET Parameter that contains a + symbol

Tags: php, datetime

I'm processing a GET request and one of the parameter is like this:

```
statusDatetime=2017-09-01T10:00:05+00:00
```

I'm retrieving that using:

```
$timestamp = $_GET['statusDatetime'];
echo $timestamp;
```

which returns `2017-09-01T10:00:05 00:00`, i.e. it replaces the `+` symbol that was after the timezone offset 05 with a space instead. This is then throwing out my attempts to convert this to another format like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s T', $timestamp);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
$newTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
```

which generates a 500 error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTimeZone() on boolean
```

for this line:

```
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
```

I can simply change the space back to a `+` symbol as the timezone offset might be negative etc, so looking for a solution that will retain the statusDatetime parameter as it was submitted.

Comment: If it was negative it wouldn't have been changed to a space...

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code as a test:

```
<?php
$timestamp = "2017-09-01T10:00:05+00:00";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s T', $timestamp);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
$newTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
echo "<div style='font-family: monospace;'>\r\n";
var_dump($timestamp, $date, $newTimestamp);
echo "</div>\r\n";
?>
```

Worked as expected with no errors. Output:

```
string(25) "2017-09-01T10:00:05+00:00" 
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { 
  ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-09-01 20:00:05.000000" 
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
  ["timezone"]=> string(16) "Australia/Sydney"
}
string(22) "09/01/2017 08:00:05 PM"
```

I would confirm that you're getting the right data as a result from your GET.

**UPDATE**

Your string is Encoded. You expected the string to be:

```
2017-09-01T10:00:05+00:00
```

It's not, as the browser encodes a lot of potentially harmful characters, its actually:

```
2017-09-01T10%3A00%3A05%2B00%3A00
```

Try this:

```
$timestamp = urldecode($_GET['statusDatetime']);
```

I tested with this:

```
<?php
$timestamp = urldecode("2017-09-01T10%3A00%3A05%2B00%3A00");
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s T', $timestamp);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
$newTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
echo "<div style='font-family: monospace;'>\r\n";
var_dump($timestamp, $date, $newTimestamp);
echo "</div>\r\n";
?>
```

The script executed properly. See More: [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Comment: You should see the issue if you pass in the timestamp as a GET parameter, e.g. `$timestamp = $_GET['statusDatetime'];`

Comment: @user982124 It's a URL Encoding issue. You think you're getting `2017-09-01T10:00:05+00:00` but in you're actually getting `2017-09-01T10%3A00%3A05%2B00%3A00` from the URL. See my update.